# Selecting A Random Cell From Another Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to select a random cell from another worksheet. The following code works if I select a random cell on the current sheet where the code is at. How can I select a random cell from another sheet?

```
Dim e
Static myList As Object
If myList Is Nothing Then
    Set myList = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
End If
If myList.Count = 0 Then
    Randomize
    For Each e In Range("D3:D32", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
        myList.Item(Rnd) = e
    Next
End If
MsgBox myList.GetByIndex(0)
myList.RemoveAt 0
```

Here's what I tried to select from another sheet.

```
Dim e
Static myList As Object
If myList Is Nothing Then
    Set myList = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
End If
If myList.Count = 0 Then
    Randomize
    For Each e In Workbooks("Test").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3:D32", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
        myList.Item(Rnd) = e
    Next
End If
MsgBox myList.GetByIndex(0)
myList.RemoveAt 0
```

Suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
For Each e In Workbooks("Test").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3:D32", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
```

you're specifying the "Test" workbook for the first call to Range, but not for the second call, nor for Rows.Count (though this will probably be the same).  As a quick fix:

```
For Each e In Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3:D32", Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("sheet1").Range("D" & Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
```

or:

```
With Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each e In .Range("D3:D32", .Range("D" & .Sheets("sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
```

Comment: Much thanks. Yes I was not referencing the range in the second call.